# Flatlist not rendering the code in react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

**My Code**

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Image,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Product = () => {
  //Initialize Firebase
  const firebaseConfig = {
//private
  };
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getDatabase();
  //Make a variable to store data
  var data = [];
  const dbRef = ref(db, "/Products");
  var indexOfData = 0;
  onValue(
    dbRef,
    (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        indexOfData++;
        const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        const childData = childSnapshot.val();
        data.push({
          ["id"]: indexOfData,
          ["key"]: childKey,
          ["value"]: childData,
        });
      });
    },
    {
      onlyOnce: true,
    }
  );
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(data);
  console.log(product);
  const navigateToAnotherPlace = (wheretonavigate) => {
    console.log("Navigating to another place");
    console.log(wheretonavigate);
  };

  const courseCard = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.cardImageCenter}>
          <Image
            style={styles.cardImage}
            source={{
              uri: item.value,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.cardHeading}>{item.key}</Text>
        <Button style={styles.cardButton} onPress={navigateToAnotherPlace(item.key)} title="View" />
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Product</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={product}
          renderItem={courseCard}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
    height: 300,
  },
  cardText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    margin: 5,
  },
  cardImage: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    resizeMode: "contain",
  },
  cardHeading: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    margin: 5,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  cardButton: {
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
    height: 300,
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  cardImageCenter: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: "70%",
    width: "100%",
  },
});

export default Product;
```

Here I can get the object from firebase but can't render it
with flatlist please add answers
When I test this app everything works fine but the flatlist does not show the data
if you have any answer please send the whole code
So what is the purpose of this screen?
Ans-> I am getting data from firebase
and I need to display that database in form of cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to refactor your code , added the state where you are storing the array `data` and using the `product` globally in your component.

I have passed the product as an argument in your `flatlist` function render.
please try and let me know the result.

```
const Product = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = React.useState([]);
  //Initialize Firebase
  const firebaseConfig = {
     //private
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getDatabase();
    //Make a variable to store data
    var data = [];
    const dbRef = ref(db, "/Products");
    var indexOfData = 0;
    onValue(
      dbRef,
      (snapshot) => {
         snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
           indexOfData++;
           const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
           const childData = childSnapshot.val();
           data.push({
              ["id"]: indexOfData,
              ["key"]: childKey,
              ["value"]: childData,
           });
        });
      },
      {
        onlyOnce: true,
      }
    );
     setProduct([...product, ...data])

   },[]);

   const navigateToAnotherPlace = (wheretonavigate) => {
      console.log("Navigating to another place");
      console.log(wheretonavigate);
   };

  const courseCard = (item) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.cardImageCenter}>
        <Image
           style={styles.cardImage}
           source={{
           uri: item.value,
           }}
         />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.cardHeading}>{item.key}</Text>
        <Button style={styles.cardButton} onPress= 
            {navigateToAnotherPlace(item.key)} title="View" />
     </View>
   );
  };
  return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text style={styles.text}>Product</Text>
         <FlatList
           data={product}
           renderItem={(product)=>courseCard(product)}
           keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
         />
     </View>
   );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

the UI and FlatList work fine for me. I think the problem in the way that you are fetching the data.
Try this:

```
const Product = () => {
   const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
   //Initialize Firebase
   const firebaseConfig = {
      //private
   };

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getDatabase();
    //Make a variable to store data
    let data = [];
    const dbRef = ref(db, "/Products");
    var indexOfData = 0;
    onValue(
      dbRef,
      (snapshot) => {
         snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
           indexOfData++;
           const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
           const childData = childSnapshot.val();
           data.push({
              ["id"]: indexOfData,
              ["key"]: childKey,
              ["value"]: childData,
           });
        });
      },
      {
        onlyOnce: true,
      }
    );
     setProducts(prv=>[...prv, ...data])
   
   },[]);
   /*.....*/
```